# Different behaviour for same code in jsp with in tomcat and weblogic server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, weblogic

**I am trying to access as list which is model by input which is integer as jsp does't make compilation error so i try below code**

hear the problem is with **Integer.parseInt(1)** and model is just list

```
 ${model.get(Integer.parseInt(1))}
```

while in tomcat it return 1.
while in weblogic it return null.

Comment: hard to say without knowing what `${model}` is. You're mentioning a list - do the lists in both environments absolutely positively have the same content? Please add more code/information

Comment: seeing as Integer.parseInt(1) is not valid Java, I would trust the one that does throw the compilation error

Comment: What about Integer.parseInt('1') or Integer.valueOf(1)  ?

Comment: thank but i want to be primitive type and to know why it not working for weblogic

Comment: 1. full version number of Tomcat, of WebLogic = ?, 2. The version attribute on web-app element in your web.xml =?

Comment: tomcat 8.0.53 and weblogic 12.1.3 and web-app it is 2.5 ,<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
 version="2.5">

Comment: @Stultuske it does't throw any compilation error Integer.parseInt(1) return null

Comment: @OlafKock ${model} ist just like list ,  Integer.parseInt(1) return null and while model .get (null) retrun 0

Comment: @Selaron its Integer.valueOf(1)